# HTMLAgilitypack read html page info with ajax calls

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilitypack for reading specific html elements of a specific url.
The problem I am facing is one of the html tag contents are filled by AJAX requests. So how can I read this ?

```
<div id="priceInfo"></div>
```

Code I used to read the url is

```
HtmlWeb _htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument _webDoc = _htmlWeb.Load(webUrl);
// HtmlNodeCollection _priceNode =  Gets the node with id priceInfo
```

The contents of this div is filled by a ajax request and i want to read the contents of this DIv after its getting filled. How can i do that

Comment: I don't think you can do it with Html Agility Pack, since it has no way of executing scripts.

Comment: Well you can simulate button click and likely post data events with some change in code HtmlAgilityPack but Ajax I am not sure if you can share the weblink you are trying to scrap. It will be good

Comment: Example : I am trying to fetch the price value of a book from a store
https://www.tanum.no/_faglitteratur/pedagogikk/pedagogiske-prosessar-otto-laurits-fuglestad-9788276742428  . On this store they are using some ajax calls to fill the price div

Comment: Have you check this url in firebug ? it is calling following url to get price by inputing some id https://www.tanum.no/tanum/rest/price/prices?p=P2_11304413&showPromotions=true

Comment: As far as i see it just require to change this parameter to get price of any book p=P2_11304413

Comment: Yes i inspect the GET requests happening on that site and i can see they are calling some Urls for fetching the price . but only known input to me was ISBN no . P2_xxxxx is the product id they are generating internally. No way for me to get that c=value

Answer (score -1):

HtmlAgilityPack is to be used at server side. from what you stating, you are trying to assert a value at client side, not at the server side.

you should look into using jquery/javascript once the ajax call is done.

```
ajax ({ ....
  .done(...) {
    // handling the return result...
    alert($("#yourHtmlId").val()); // show one of your html tag value attribute.
  }   
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I am trying to read the contents of an html page from a console application and i guess this tip is not related to that

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem.
Even from the script you can identify which control is loaded by ajax call, you will still not get the data. because the page on the server side you are not mimicking the ajax behavior.